# Bind Images To RadMosaicTile

Tags: telerik, windows-store-apps

I am using RadMosaicTile in my windows store application. I want to bind images with it.
I tried this

```
RadMosaicHubTile tile = new RadMosaicHubTile();
tile.ImageSources.Add("Image1.jpg");
tile.ImageSources.Add("Image2.jpg");
```

but it is not working. images are not binded.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The have this code sample on the [telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/hubtile/binding-radmosaichubtile-imagesources.aspx) - does this work for you?

```
Collection<object> imageSources = new Collection<object>();
ImageSource image = GetImageFromWeb();
imageSources.Add(image);

RadMosaicHubTile hubTile = new RadMosaicHubTile();
hubTile.CreateImageSource = (source) =>
{
    return (ImageSource)source;
};
hubTile.ImageSources = imageSources;
```

Comment: what this line does...hubTile.CreateImageSource = (source) =>
{
    return (ImageSource)source;
};